# Rational formal and coformal space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In rational homotopy theory there are two concepts,formal and coformal spaces.I want to know example of a space which is
1)not formal and coformal,
2)rationally hyperbolic and not coformal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this paper you will find examples that fits with your first question:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040938303000053
"Elliptic rational spaces whose cohomologies and homotopies are isomorphic"
Tetsu Nishimotoa, Hiroo Shiga, Toshihiro Yamaguchi.

The authors consider a family of elliptic spaces that are not formal nor coformal.
These examples are very interesting, they build two simply-connected closed smooth manifolds $M_1$, $M_2$ such that

1. they have isomorphic rational cohomology algebra,
2. they have isomorphic rational homotopy Lie algebras $\pi_*(\Omega M_i)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$,
3. they are not rationally homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @Davic C,Thank you sir.The link you gave is not opening.Can you send me the email address of anyone of the authors?I tried to find by googling,but failed.